# How to query repeatedly tasks in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, calendar

I'm making a Calendar APP with PHP and MongoDB.

I have some datas in collection(MONGODB) like this:

```
{
    'NAME' : 'test1',
    'YEAR' : '2014',
    'MONTH' : 'EVERY',
    'DAY' : 5
}

{
    'NAME' : 'test2',
    'YEAR' : 'EVERY',
    'MONTH' : 12,
    'DAY' : 1
}

{
    'NAME' : 'test3',
    'YEAR' : 2013,
    'MONTH' : 3,
    'DAY' : 'EVERY'
} 

{
    'NAME' : 'test4',
    'YEAR' : 2014,
    'MONTH' : 3,
    'DAY' : 15
}
```

How can I get this with MongoDB:

1. all data before 2014-03-01
2. all data after 2013-01-01
3. all data between 2013-01-01 and 2015-12-31
4. all data between 2013-04-12 and 2015-03-01

Thanks!

Comment: Not a fan of downvoters just because a new poster did not follow the code formatting rules. But make it a note to do so in the future. There are clear guidelines given when you first post.

Answer (score 0):

Your modelling here is looking for the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to compare evaluation of "EVERY" with the actual values you want to match. Note the forms, and that "you" will need to determine your logic here based on the conditions you are providing.

What that means is "you" need to determine where "less than" or "less than or equal to" applies given your requirement when constructing the query.

Here is the basic JSON form, you do know how to translate JSON as PHP syntax I hope:

Question 1:

```js
db.calendar.find({
   "$or": [
       { "YEAR": "EVERY" },
       { "YEAR": { "$lte": 2014 } }
   ],
   "$or": [
       { "MONTH": "EVERY" },
       { "MONTH": { "$lt": 3 } },
    ],
    "$or": [
       { "DAY": "EVERY" },
       { "DAY": { "$gt": 1 } }
    ]
})
```

Question 2:

```js
db.calendar.find({
   "$or": [
       { "YEAR": "EVERY" },
       { "YEAR": { "$gte": 2013 } }
   ],
   "$or": [
       { "MONTH": "EVERY" },
       { "MONTH": { "$gte": 1 } },
    ],
    "$or": [
       { "DAY": "EVERY" },
       { "DAY": { "$gt": 1 } }
    ]
})
```

Question 3:

```js
db.calendar.find({
   "$or": [
       { "YEAR": "EVERY" },
       { "YEAR": { "$gte": 2013, "$lte": 2015 } }
   ]
})
```

Bottom line is I get:

1. 1,3,4
2. 1,3,4
3. 2,3,4

Which I believe to be the matching results.

If you are getting used to the "syntax" here, the **all** query arguments in a MongoDB query are "implicitly" an "AND" condition. There is an [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator, but that is only needed when you need to specify more than one condition for the same field. See the documentation on the link.

**Note**: I cleaned up the data syntax in your question a bit, but I did not change things such as one "YEAR" being a string and others that are numeric types. Your data really needs to be consistent, so I hope it is, otherwise you have **more** `$or` conditions. But just a note to say you **cannot** "cast" types otherwise in a query.

---

Your additional question:

```js
db.calendar.find({
    "$or": [
        { "YEAR": "EVERY" },
        { "YEAR": 2013, "MONTH": "EVERY" },
        { "YEAR": 2013, "MONTH": 4, "DAY": "EVERY" },
        { "YEAR": 2013, "MONTH": 4, "DAY": { "$gt": 12 } },
        { "YEAR": 2013, "MONTH": { "$gte": 5 } },
        { "YEAR": 2014 },
        { "YEAR": 2015, "MONTH": "EVERY" },
        { "YEAR": 2015, "MONTH": { "$lte": 2 } } 
    ]
})
```

Really this is all about establishing the conditions that would be true for the range of dates you supply. In this case you are spanning a more than a year so "EVERY" is a true selection for YEAR, as would be 2014 as there is no restriction in that range.

The same applies in the the places where filtering would apply, as "EVERY" for DAY in MONTH 4 would be true as it is less than the date, and so on with the other conditions.

The point is, as is shown by all the query forms here, you need to look at the logic you are applying for these ranges and "build" that logic to suit the conditions that possibly match.

What you have embarked on is a "custom type" and as such there are not "built in" operators to deal with what you have created. Everything here is a set of matching "and" conditions that could be applied and then tested by implementing logical "or" to see if one of those conditions fits.

Comment: Thanks, That helps a lot. But I have one more question. how can I get all data between 2013-04-12 and 2015-03-01?

Comment: @Winmain I sometimes miss responses so there is the delay. Added more information for you, but I think you need to understand these are not "fixed" queries, but that you need to "build" your conditions to suit what range you want. MongoDB queries are essentially data structures that can be manipulated like any other data.